# dialing numbers after call is initiated in lync

Tags: c#, phone-call, lync

I am initiating a call using **Lync** Sdk,
I am making an application that dials to an automated voice message service and i want to dial numbers after the call is initiated to automatically choose menu options.
so i need to basically dial digits from code after the call is initiated.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get to the `AudioChannel` on the Conversation:

```
var avModality = (AVModality)conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo];
var audioChannel = avModality.AudioChannel;
```

Then you can send DTMF tones down the channel:

```
avModality.AudioChannel.BeginSendDtmf("1", SendDtmfComplete, null));
```

Bear in mind that the service on the other end may change the order of the menu options, or may require a delay before sending the tone.

If you think this is the right answer, please mark it as accepted, to help anyone else browsing the question. Thanks!